# How to set a property of an object as required on one operation and not required on other operation on WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

For example I have these complexTypes:

```
<!-- will be use as a request parameter -->
<complextType name="enrollStudentRequest">     
 <sequence>
  <element name="student" type="Student" />
 </sequence>
</complexType>

<!-- will be use as an operation response -->
<complextType name="retrieveStudentsResponse">
 <sequence>
  <element name="student" type="Student" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
 </sequence>
</complexType>

<!-- domain model -->
<complexType name="Student">
 <sequence name="id" type="long" />
 <sequence name="firstName" type="string" />
 <sequence name="lastName" type="string" />
</complexType>
```

**The question:**
How can I enforce so that on "enrollStudentRequest", Student.id is required BUT not required on "retrieveStudentsResponse"? Can I enforce such a restriction on the WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the schema in its current form, no. You either need to restructure the WSDL/schema, or keep it as optional in the schema, and then perform additional manual validation in Java.

Comment: so,  what i'm hearing is that we cannot do this kind of restriction in wsdl alone. i'd better do the validation in java then.

Comment: No, you *can* do it in WSDL, but you'll need to define two different `Student` types, one with an optional ID, and one with a mandatory ID. But then they wouldn't be the same type any more, which may or may not matter to do.

Comment: that's what we are trying to do, avoiding to define many objects with the same properties. thanks!